# How can I set HttpPost attribute globally in Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am working on an existing Web API in which I need to make all actions HttpPost based. For achieving this I am using configuration like this.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional },
                constraints: new { httpMethod= new HttpMethodConstraint(HttpMethod.Post) }
            );
```

But this is not working on actions having name strating with "Get". But It is working fine when I am decorating action with [HttpPost] atrribute like this

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult GetUserByName()
```

There are many actions like this and I want to avoid decorating each Action with [HttpPost] atrribute. Is there any way to set [HttpPost] atrribute globally?

Comment: Why would you do that? I cannot get the meaning of why someone should make all actions with POST method

Comment: It is the requirement from the client-side.